# unibiased flip: Find the probability of how many times heads and how many times tails

Tags: python

i am trying to develop a function which prints the probability of heads given as number of times h was printed divided by total number of times h or t was printed.

Here's my code
def unbiasedFlip(n,p):

```
for i in range(n+1):
    p=Pr(Heads)
    n=Totalflips
    if num1>=p and num2<p:
        print(Heads)
    elif num1>=(1-p) and num2<(1-p):
        print(Tails)
```

num1 and num2 are the two random numbers which are supposed to be generated through if function. and pr for probablity. when i run the program i get error that i am not defining pr or heads.

Comment: `Pr` and `Heads` aren't going to be magically defined for you...

Comment: You don't define TotalFlips or Tails either. You must assign a value to a variable before you reference it. Google Python variables to get the basics.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This code may not be what you're really looking for, however I thought it could help you in some way... I hope so...

Anyway, before viewing my ptential solution, I suggest you try to learn Python (synthax, how to create functions, create random numbers, etc). You'll see that it is quite easy to learn and you'll totally like it! :P

You can find several ways to learn Python (books, online courses / docs, a friend addicted to Python XD, etc).

Check the following link for example: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Keep in mind that having a clear and understandable code helps us understand what is your problem, and gives you the best chance to get a better answer to your question ;).

---

Here is a simple code, **I suggest you focus in reading the comments carefully**:

```
import random 

# The function "prob_head" below return the number of head divided by the number of coin toss
# The input variable "number_toss" is number of times we toss a coin
def prob_head(number_toss):

    # "heads" is our number of heads. 
    # Initially it is equal to 0
    heads = 0

    # We toss a coin "number_toss" times...
    for i in range(0, number_toss):
        # We create a random number "flip" comprised in {0,1}        
        flip = int(random.random()*2)

        # Let's say we follow the following rule:
        # If "flip" = 0, then it's a head
        # Else, if "flip" = 1, then it's a tail

        if (flip == 0):
            # "flip" = 0, so it's a head !
            # We have to increment the number of "heads" by 1:
            heads=heads + 1 

    return float(heads)/number_toss

# Here's a test of our function: "prob_head"
my_number_toss = 100
my_head_probability = prob_head(my_number_toss)

print "Probability of heads = "+str(my_head_probability)
```

**Example of output:**

> Probability of heads = 0.41

---

The code above gives you an idea of simulating a normal coin tossing.

After re-reading your comments, I think I understood a bit more what you really wanted so I added this additional part...

**The below code represents a way to simulate a "tricked" / "fake" coin tossing game**.

Pay attention to the comments I made...

```
# The function "unbiasedFlip" returns the average probability of heads considering "n" coin 
# The variable "p" is a fixed probability condition for getting a head.
def unbiasedFlip(n, p):

    # The number of heads, initially set to 0
    heads = 0

    # We toss a coin n times...
    for i in range(0, n):

        # We generate "prob_heads": a random float number such that "prob_heads" < 1
        prob_heads = float(random.random())

        # If "prob_heads" is greater of equal to "p", then we have a head 
        # and we increase the number of heads "heads" by 1:
        if prob_heads>=p:
            heads = heads+1

    # We return the average probability of heads, considering n coin tosses
    # Note: we don't need to return the average prob. for Tails since:
    # it's equal to 1-Avg_Prob(Heads)              
    return float(heads)/n

# An example for testing our function...
# We consider 100 coin toss
my_number_toss = 100

# We want a Head only if our generated probability of head is greater or equal to 0.8
# In fact, considering that the random number generator generates equally probability numbers
# (which means that it provides as many chance to give a Tail or a Head)
# it would be like saying: "we want a probability of 1-0.8 =0.2 chance of getting a head"
my_defined_prob_heads = 0.8

# We get our average probability of heads...
average_prob_heads = unbiasedFlip(my_number_toss, my_defined_prob_heads)
# We get our average probability of tails = 1-Avg_Prob(Heads)
average_prob_tails = 1-average_prob_heads

# We print the results...
print "- Number of toss = "+str(my_number_toss)
print "- Defined probability for head = "+str(my_defined_prob_heads)
print "- Average P(Heads) for n tosses = "+str(average_prob_heads)
print "- Average P(Tails) for n tosses = "+str(average_prob_tails)
```

**Example of output:**

```
- Number of toss = 100
- Defined probability for head = 0.8
- Average P(Heads) for n tosses = 0.24
- Average P(Tails) for n tosses = 0.76
```

Hope this helps mate.

Let me know if you have a question or if something is not clear.

Comment: thanks it did helped a little. but i have to print probability of tails also. The most confusing part is how do i generate two random numbers. because i have to show if the first number is greater than the probability and second number is less than probability than its H. and it first number is greater than or equal to (1-p) and second number is less than (1-p) then its t. I am kinda confused about the question itsefl. But thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hey mate! :) The probability of Tails is given by the probability of Heads: `P(Tails) = 1-P(Heads)`. So, for example, if you have a probability of heads equal to `0.41` (like in the example above), you'll have `P(Tails)= 1-0.41= 0.59`. To generate a random number, you can use the python's `random`. For example, in the code above, I generated a random number in {0,1} by using: `int(random.random()*2)`. Oh! I think I understand what you want! Aren't the 2 random numbers you want to generate the probabilities of heads and tails?

Comment: Hey mate, I re-edited my post, taking into account your comments. You should check the last part of my post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, we generate a random coinflip sequence:

```
import random
n = 100 # number of flips
p = 0.5 # P(Heads) - 0.5 is a fair coin
flips = ['H' if (random.random() < p) else 'T' for flipnr in xrange(n)]
print flips
```

Next, we count the number of heads and tails:

```
nheads = flips.count('H')
ntails = flips.count('T')
```

and calculate the chance:

```
phead = float(nheads) / (nheads + ntails)
```

Note that (in Python 2) we need to force floating-point division by casting one of the variables to `float` (this is fixed in Python 3).